# Eclipse suggesting blank imports

Tags: eclipse

I don't recall when this happened, but whenever I attempt to use suggested fixes, imports will frequently show without the actual class it's suggestion to import, as shown below. This is not the case for all imports, some show up. But it seems fairly consistent with which ones are not showing up. It makes updating things annoying because I have to guess to see if I'm getting the correct import.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOfz1.jpg

Comment: Have you installed a new plugin recently? Try disabling it temporarily. Otherwise do yo see anything strange in the `.metadata/logs` file? That may help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Reinstalling did nothing, no logs file exists